# google map v3 and json converting currentdirection to json string and back to object problem

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

I am storing a direction object in database after converting it to a string using json.stringify

when i want to redraw i read that string and i used json.parse to convert it back to direction object and assigned that object as follows

```
currentDirections = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
var hehe = JSON.stringify(currentDirections)    
hehe = JSON.parse(hehe)
directionsDisplay.setDirections(hehe);
```

the variable hehe alerted as object but the list line of code throws an error which is as follows...

> Invalid value
>   for property : [object
>   Object] [Break on this error]
>   W[A].bindTo=function(a,b,c,d){c=c||a;var...unction
>   jf(a){a=a.g[1];return a!=j?a:""}

i used the other way like eval... i can get the object back but when assigned it is showing the same error.

i would like to have some suggestions, answers, hints and anything.

**EDIT:**

**after trying with ext js i got the same problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a work around for this.
and published in my site.

http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

Answer (score 0):

The firebug may be required to reinstall.though I am not sure and I have not faced this issue.
However, you can use the following link.This link talks about a similar issue.
http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/da5b804949ec7e3c

Comment: IT IS NOTHING OT DO WITH FIREBUG. i have to tell you that this error occurred in google's js file and not of firebug.

Comment: anyway we need to run in firefox too... isn't it? i am having firefox version 3.0.0.10 . I doubt that older version browsers will not do the expected job with respecto gmap v3. would this be a case?

Comment: could be,exactly you can find out the issue by running this in IE and various browsers.So you can find out the root cause.